# Upload an image from facebook to my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I am doing an online image editor, (it currently allows the user to choose an image from his computer and upload it to the server where it gets edited) and I want to allow the user to upload an image from his facebook account, instead from his computer. since am completely lost on how to do this, is there an official api? What is the best way to give the user the ability to browse his facebook album and upload the photo

**Edit:** The api can be found on the facebook developers website with enough hints to get you started.

**Important clues for this task with my experience**

> Permission scopes
>
> Indicate to the user of the required permissions somewhere in your website
>
> Facebook needs a very detailed overview of the tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook api, check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos

**or**

you could put in some instructions on how they can copy paste the location of their picture on facebook, to your website. Right-click image -> copy location. Like getting the location of a picture that you would want to share anywhere.

Comment: as i have never worked with facebook api before can you point me to a tutorial or even explain me the steps? as i understand it i need to send the user to his facebook album, he will chose a picture and comeback with (hopefully) a url for the picture so i can get the data with php, how are the permissions solved for this task

Comment: I have never worked with it either. An API will let you send a web request with javascript or PHP and return a set of data. The user will probably get a popup to logon or to allow the access to his facebook. You can find the quickstart guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0. You just have to include a little piece of javascript to include the API. Don't forget you will also need an API key.

Comment: cheers ill look into it, for your second suggestion although i prefer it much more than getting involved with the fb api, the person who needs the website doesn't like the idea :(